# Unable to deploy Googlecloud function despite adding trigger

Tags: email, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have the following cloud function which is trying to use sendgrid to send email when a new user signs up. This was a modified version of original firebase repo on how to send emails using nodemailer. This was working fine earlier with out sendgrid functionality. So, what you see below is a heavily modified version of the code.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const SEND_GRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sengrid.key


const sgMail = require('@sengrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(SEND_GRID_API_KEY);




// Your company name to include in the emails
// TODO: Change this to your app or company name to customize the email sent.
const APP_NAME = 'Asia Rubber';

// [START sendWelcomeEmail]
/**
 * Sends a welcome email to new user.
 */
// [START onCreateTrigger]
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((event) => {
  // [END onCreateTrigger]
  // [START eventAttributes]
  const user = event.data; // The Firebase user.

  const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
  const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user.
  // [END eventAttributes]

  return sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName);
});
// [END sendWelcomeEmail]

// [END sendByeEmail]

// Sends a welcome email to the given user.
function sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName) {
  const msg = {
    from: `${APP_NAME} <Welcome@rubber.asia>`,
    to: email,
    subject: 'Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!',


    //custom templates
    templateId: 'e3978a51-5343-4b3a-9128-8c4a493f265e'
  };
  return sgMail.send(msg)
  .then( () => console.log('email sent'))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

when I am trying to deploy I am getting an error

```
PS E:\Cloudfunctions\erubberFunctions\functions> firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'erubber'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint E:\Cloudfunctions\erubberFunctions\functions
> eslint .


E:\Cloudfunctions\erubberFunctions\functions\index.js
  79:14  warning  Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Cloudfunctions\erubberFunctions\functions\index.js:5:53)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at C:\Users\bhara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:18:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bhara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:38:3)
```

So, from my code the only key I have is sendgrid api key which I already added like this

```
firebase functions:config:set sendgrid.key=SG.YOUR_API_KEY
```

No quotes for the key btw.

What am I doing wrong? 
Also in general is there anything wrong with the code in general? Tks

Answer (score 2):

Your cloud function has a small typo. You're trying to access the property `sengrid` (Missing the `d` in `send`).

The correct line of code should be;

`const SEND_GRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key`

Comment: Tks for spotting that, not only there.Few other places as well. But after correcting that and deploying I am unable to recieve any email!

Comment: @JackyBoi That sounds like a different problem. I am going to vote to close this question as a typo (it's unlikely that anyone in a similar situation is going to find your question), and I recommend that you open an new question with details of the problem. Please be incredibly specific there on what is happening, as nobody is going to be able to help otherwise.